# React Native: setState in finally()

Tags: android, react-native, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I enable/disable network activity indicator with the following code in my "render()" method:

```
{this.state.networkActivity && <NetworkActivityIndicator/>}
```

Now when I put

```
this.setState({networkActivity: true});
```

before "fetch()" and

```
this.setState({networkActivity: false});
```

in ".finally()" like this:

```
this.setState({networkActivity: true});
fetch(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
.finally(this.setState({networkActivity: false}));
```

the indicator DOESN'T show at all. Any idea why?

Moving the "this.setState({networkActivity: false})" to ".then()" or ".catch()" block solves the problem (as workaround). Indicator shows up.

Tested on device with Android 6. React Native version: 0.51

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since fetch is a web standard it uses the standard Promise API available to the majority of web browsers. This means that the method "Finally" doesn't exist.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
Promise.all()
Promise.prototype.catch()
Promise.prototype.then()
Promise.race()
Promise.reject()
Promise.resolve()
```

I believe those are all the methods available. You could create your own Finally method and call it as a Promise.resolve() in order to complete your Promise chain.

However, if the method is available, you would need to call a function within the parenthesis.

```
// incorrect -> ...finally(setState...)
// correct -> ...finally(function(){ this.setState() /* this might not be scoped properly here */ })
// correct -> ...finally(()=>this.setState())
```

Comment: Funny thing is that when I changed it to `.finally(() => this.setState({networkActivity: false}))` then it works!! Confused...

Comment: nice find! I updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Seems ".finally()" is under spec right now and probably will be part of standard but on the other hand seems also my "babel" understands it already.

Answer (score 2):

`finally`, like `then` and `catch` takes a function, in your example you're providing the return value of `this.setState()` to `finally`.

Both `setState` calls get run immediately.

Essentially the code you have is approximately functionally something like this:

```
this.setState({networkActivity: true});
const returnValueOfSetState = this.setState({networkActivity: false});

fetch(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
.finally(returnValueOfSetState);
```

This means that you set `networkActivity` to `true` and then immediately set it back to `false`. Then when `finally` happens it tries to execute `returnValueOfSetState` which I believe is `undefined`, so it's a no-op.

This is just a mistake in syntax, what you actually want is something like:

```
this.setState({networkActivity: true});

fetch(...)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
.finally(() => {
  this.setState({networkActivity: false});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`finally` is not supported in React Native's fetch. But the core team plan to change the fetch polyfill soon (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23313), which might fix it.

If you want change the [StatusBar's network activity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#networkactivityindicatorvisible), here is what you can do.

Override `fetch` function, to inject the network activity loader.

```
const globalFetch = global.fetch;

global.fetch = (url: string, params: Object): Promise<*> => {
  return new Promise((resolve: any => void, reject: string => void) => {
    StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(true);

    // TODO: use Promise.finally with RN >= 0.60
    globalFetch(url, params)
      .then((response: any) => {
        resolve(response);
        StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(false);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        reject(error);
        StatusBar.setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible(false);
      });
  });
};
```